# Nested integral with same function at every integral being multiplied an integrated again.

Tags: calculus, integration, physics, multiple-integral, cauchy-integral-formula

$$\int_z^{\infty}f(z_1)\int_{z_1}^\infty f(z_2) \cdots \int_{z_{n-1}}^\infty f(z_n)dz_ndz_{n-1}\cdots dz_2dz_1$$
Just for reference we could also write it as

$$\int_z^\infty \int_{z_1}^\infty\cdots\int_{z_{n-2}}^\infty\int_{z_{n-1}}^\infty f(z_n)f(z_{n-1})\cdots f(z_2)f(z_1)dz_ndz_{n-1}\cdots dz_2dz_1$$
How is one to solve this integral I first thought to use cauchy but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: do you know fubini

Comment: Why is this tagged with physics when there's no such context in the post?

Comment: @TsemoAristide, no what is fubini?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Integrals like that appear frequently in Quantum Many Body Theoty.

Comment: @FelixMarin I was trying to remind the OP to include context.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin 0 k. That's pretty fine.